# fractional scaling messes up LibreOffice auto-filters

Tags: nvidia, libreoffice, scaling

I can see the LibreOffice Calc auto-filter values, but the moment my mouse leaves the little expand-triangle the selector disappears, making auto-filter unusable. This only happens when fractional scaling is enabled on with my 4K monitor. Is there a setting that fixes this, or a workaround?

Ubuntu 20.10, GeForce GTX 1050, mvidia-driver-455

Comment: Submitted bug with video clip https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1913333

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to 21.04 fixed my issue.